# Batch video convert with FFmpeg in Ubuntu: combine image and audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a folder full of audio file with .mp3 .amr and .wav extension. I have a image.jpg. What I want is combine the image.jpg with every audio file in that folder and convert them to separate vidoe.mp4 file. How do I do it with FFmpge in Ubuntu? I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding sound to a video is straightforward

```
ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i input.png -i input.mp3 -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 -preset medium -acodec aac -vf scale=1280:-2,format=yuv420p output.mp4
```

- `-i` input.mp3 The audio filename
- `-acodec copy` Copies the audio from the input stream to the output stream
- `-s` is the output resolution of the video

Basically, just change the `input.png` to the filename of your picture, and the `input.mp3` to the audio file.  Finally, alter `output.mp4` to the destination file name you want.

This is a very simple method for doing what you want, but it is possible to script this in the following way:

```
#! /bin/bash
###################################################################
picture="input.jpg"  # Change this to the file name of your picture
###################################################################
for i in *.mp3; do
  ffmpeg -framerate 60 -f image2 -i $picture -i input.mp3 -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 -preset medium -acodec aac -vf scale=1280:-2,format=yuv420p "${i%.*}.".mp4
done
```

Put the filename of your picture in the top, paste it into a file, save it as something like `convert.sh`.  Change the permissions `chmod 777 convert.sh`, then run it `./convert.sh`

It should read all the mp3 files, add a picture and output an mp4 file with the same name as the mp3.

If you want to do the same with wav files or amr, just change `for i in *.mp3; do` to `for i in *.wav; do` or `for i in *.amr; do`.

Hope that helps!

Good luck :)

Comment: For the [image file demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) `-f image2` is superfluous (but you may need it in a script). Use `-framerate` instead of `-r` for image input. Instead of declaring an arbitrary bitrate use `-crf`. If you want to scale it use `-s` as an output option, not input. There is no preset named "normal". If you want to declare a preset use `-preset` because `-vpre` is used for custom, user created presets. Not all players can handle MP3 audio in MP4 container. For more info see [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264). Typo: `$720`.

Comment: Lastly, you'll need to use `-vf format=yuv420p` or `-pix_fmt yuv420p` output options or the output won't play on dumb players like QuickTime or WMP.

Comment: Updated to reflect your comments, and fixed minor typos.

Comment: Thanks for fixing up the code.  It was on the fly to quickly answer the question :)

Answer (score 0):

to combine same image with different mp3 files resulting in seperate avi files with the same name as the mp3 file, the code is as follows: for i in *.mp3;   do name=`echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1`;   echo "$name";   ffmpeg -y -i image.jpg -i "$i" "${name}.avi"; done. Just change the name of your image file.